# Calculate all numbers from a Multiple selection return the total sum Multiselect + jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I am trying to sum multiple values into one value and append it to input value.
jQuery UPDATED:

```
afterSelect: function(value){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/police/get_res_price?price=' + value,
            success: function (data) {
                var initial_price = $('.give-me-money').val();
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(obj, function(booking_price, value) {
                    initial_price += value.BOOKING_PRICE;
                });
                $('.give-me-money').val(initial_price); //set total
                console.log(initial_price);
            }
        });
        this.qs1.cache();
        this.qs2.cache();
    },
```

HTML:

```
<select id='custom-headers' multiple='multiple' class="searchable">
<?php foreach ($get_reservations as $res_option): ?>
<option value="<?php print $res_option->DBASE_ID; ?>"><?php print $res_option->DBASE_ID; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<input class="give-me-money" type="text">
```

Each click log me number for example, 5117, 547, 987, 54. and appends it to the input upon the last selection of the multiselect. i want someway to say 'wait' sum 5117+547+987+54 and append 6705 to the input value, how would i do that?

Comment: Have a variable to save your subtotal?

Comment: @Shilly any ideas how to execute it?

Comment: Explain better what exactly you want, since I don't understand. Do you want the sum of all selected BOOKING_PRICE's to update every time an extra price is selected? or does the user have to press a button to get his total? Or?

Comment: @Shilly I want to sum each click the value. and at the end append to the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all values to the same variable and then set the value to the `.give-me-money` field. Also change your html:

**html**

```
<input class="give-me-money" type="text" value="0">
```

**javascript**

```
afterSelect: function(value){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/police/get_res_price?price=' + value,
        success: function (data) {

            var initial_price = parseInt($('.give-me-money').val());
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            $.each(obj, function(booking_price, value) {
                console.log(value.BOOKING_PRICE);
                initial_price += parseInt(value.BOOKING_PRICE);
            });
            $('.give-me-money').val(initial_price); //set total
        }
    });
    this.qs1.cache();
    this.qs2.cache();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bas, removed the reset of the input now instead of sum i am getting a long number after each click: for example:
286,220,152,382 becomes: 286220152382 instead of 1040, why's that?

Comment: + also concatenates strings, so one of your values is a string instead fo a number. so wrap all number strings into a parseInt(x, 10) or parseFloat(x, 10). Hence I would just save it as a (non-local to the ajax call) variable.

Comment: can't get it working.. could you provide example please? note the numbers log as numbers not strings. perhaps different problem?

Comment: success: function (data) {
 var obj = JSON.parse(data),
  total = 0;
 $.each(obj, function(booking_price, value) {
  console.log(value.BOOKING_PRICE);
  total += parseInt(value.BOOKING_PRICE, 10);
 });
 $('.give-me-money').val(total);
}

Comment: whats the output in give-me-money at the moment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95252/discussion-between-ilan-hasanov-and-shilly).

Answer (score 2):

Showing the code from chat:

```
afterSelect: function(value){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/police/get_res_price?price=' + value,
                success: function (data) {
                    var initial_price = parseInt($('.give-me-money').val(), 10) || 0;
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    $.each(obj, function(booking_price, value) {
                        initial_price += parseInt(value.BOOKING_PRICE, 10);
                    });
                    $('.give-me-money').val(initial_price); //set total
                    console.log(initial_price);
                }
            });
            this.qs1.cache();
            this.qs2.cache();
        },
```